# What are the values for AuthenticationMethod?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm making a request to `/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient`

with the JSON

`{
  "authenticationMethod": "userid",
  "returnUrl": "http://localhost:3000/rooms/07bfcdf24f455ff14964f0e14c8d6825/finished",
  "userId": "5a44ea44-02be-4926-8c3d-66cb85523799"
}`

and getting the error

`{
  "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",
  "message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. The value of AuthenticationMethod is invalid."
}`

EDIT:

Another thing i failed to mention, is the envelope was created with compositeTemplates.

Comment: replace `userid` with `userId` note difference in case

Comment: @Lashane the [documentation](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Post Recipient View.htm) shows `"userId"` in camel case.

Second, the error is the value of the property `"authenticationMethod"`

Answer (score 5):

From the SOAP WSDL (https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx?wsdl) - these values also work for REST (lowercase):

Password
Email
PaperDocuments
HTTPBasicAuth
SSLMutualAuth
X509Certificate
Kerberos
SingleSignOn_CASiteminder
SingleSignOn_InfoCard
SingleSignOn_MicrosoftActiveDirectory
SingleSignOn_Passport
SingleSignOn_SAML
SingleSignOn_Other
Smartcard
RSASecureID
Biometric
None
KnowledgeBasedAuth

Answer (score 0):

The following values should all be valid, though note that this might not be a full list:

```
"None"
"Email"
"Password"
"HTTPBasicAuth"
"X509Certificate"
"KnowledgeBasedAuth"
```